# Is it possible to have an "S-shaped" animation velocity curve in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, velocity, jquery-animate, slide

On the Apple iPhone, the slide animation velocities follow an S-shaped curve where it starts off slow, accelerates and then slows down at the end. See this article to see a visualization of what I mean:
http://watchingapple.com/2009/11/a-closer-look-at-iphone-transition-animations/

Is it possible to do this with JQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only options in straight jQuery are `swing` (the default) and `linear`, but with jQuery UI you have [all of these options](http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/#easing).

I think `swing` is S-shaped already, but there are definitely more options in jQuery UI.

Comment: Did not know jQuery UI had a demo page for it.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out easeInOutCubic and easeInOutQuart [here](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/).